# Filter method in Python is not working as expected for strings

Tags: python

I am filtering a list of strings according to the following condition.

```py
list_of_strings = ["foo-bar", "foo", "bar"]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x is not "foo-bar", list_of_strings)))

>>> ["foo-bar", "foo", "bar"] # This is output. But I expected "foo-bar" to be removed
```

But this is working fine with `!=`

How is this happening?

Comment: is not is same as != .The compiler now produces a SyntaxWarning when identity checks (is and is not) are used with certain types of literals (e.g. strings, numbers).

Comment: @Joelinton The Python compiler doesn't issue any warnings. Some linter you're employing might.

Comment: TL;DR: never expect any particular behaviour from `is` unless you're comparing object instances you have explicitly assigned to two variables like `a = Obj(); b = a`. In any other case it very much depends on implementation details how `is` will work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the filtering condition. Should be:

```
lambda x: x != "foo-bar"
```

To compare two strings use `!=` and `==` (equality test).

`is` is a test for an identical object.

---

```
>>> "A" is "A"
True
```

This is an efect of an optimisation called *interning*. If a constant is used several times, the Python interpreter tries to save only one copy of it. You cannot rely on that.

```
>>> "a".upper() is "A"
False

>>> "a".upper() == "A"
True
```

Comment: I understand, but "foo-bar" is "foo-bar" will return True and "foo-bar" is not "foo-bar" will return False.

Comment: Hence, this should be working